# sorting the table data when not using react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to avoid using react state for better performance. However, i have no idea on how can i sort table data. I tried to have sort function in the column that needs sorting with the type("asc" or "desc") and based on name or title or like that. This is the configuration and code for my table

code

```
const sortBy = (data, key, type = "asc") => data.sort((a, b) => a[key].toLowerCase() < b[key].toLowerCase());

const columns = {
  name: {
    key: "name",
    label: "Listing Name",
    css: "color: #444; font-size: 1.1rem; font-weight: bold;",
    content: (item: Object) => (
      <NameColumn>
        {item.url && <Avatar name={item.name} url={item.url} size={80} type="square" />}
        <NameWrapper>
          <Name>{item.name}</Name>
          {item.location && <SubName color='#797979'>{item.location}</SubName>}
        </NameWrapper>
      </NameColumn>
    )
  },
  agent: {
    key: "agent",
    label: "Agent",
    sort: (data: Array<Object>, item: Object) => sortBy(data, item, 'desc'),
    isSortable: true,
    hideOnPhone: true
  },
  price: {
    key: "price",
    label: "Prices",
    hideOnPhone: true
  },
};

const userData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Rahul",
    location: 'Delhi',
    agent: "hello man",
    price: '$15000',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Sachin Tendulkar",
    location: 'Delhi',
    agent: "Mumbai Inc",
    price: '$15000',
  },

];

const rowConfig = {
  uniqueKey: "id",
  css: `
    height: 100px;
    &:hover {
      background-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.2)};
    }
  `,
  onClick: (e, item) => {
    console.log("row was clicked", item);
  }
};

type Props = {
  location: Object
};

const Tables = ({ location }: Props) => {
  const queries = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  return (
    <Main>
      <Table
        rowConfig={rowConfig}
        columns={columns}
        data={userData}
        totalPages={10}
        currentPage={
          queries.has("page") ? parseInt(queries.get("page"), 10) : 1
        }
        basePageLink={""}
      />
    </Main>
  );
};

export default Tables;


const Table = ({
  columns,
  data = [],
  rowConfig: { uniqueKey = "id", css , onClick } = {},
  currentPage,
  totalPages,
  basePageLink
}: Props) => {
  const headerColumns = () =>
    Object.keys(columns).map(key => (
      <Th
        key={key}
        align={columns[key].align}
        width={columns[key].width}
        onClick={() => columns[key].isSortable && columns[key].sort(data, key)}
        css={columns[key].cssHeader}
      >
        {columns[key].label ? columns[key].label : ""}
      </Th>
    ));
  const cell = (key, item) => (
    <Td
      key={key}
      align={columns[key].align}
      width={columns[key].width}
      css={columns[key].css}
    >
      {columns[key].content ? columns[key].content(item) : item[key]}
    </Td>
  );
  const row = (item: Object) => (
    <Tr
      key={item[uniqueKey]}
      css={css}
      onClick={onClick ? (e: Event) => onClick(e, item) : null}
    >
      {Object.keys(columns).map(key => cell(key, item))}
    </Tr>
  );
  return (
    <Main>
      <T>
        <thead>
          <tr>{headerColumns()}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{data.map(i => row(i))}</tbody>
      </T>
      <TablePagination
        currentPage={currentPage}
        totalPages={totalPages}
        basePageLink={basePageLink}
      />
    </Main>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

The way i am doing wont work cause i am not using the react state which will notify react that the state has changed so re-render the agent column(for now sorting is used in agent column only so).

Any suggesstions? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can manually force an update (forceUpdate) but I cannot see the benefits on not using state and then forcing renders. Use the state instead and use shouldComponentUpdate for managing when to re render

Comment: can you write this in answer section with sample code, please?